# Jersey client side receive pojo us bytes

Tags: javascript, java, json, jakarta-ee, jersey

Is there any possibility to have a Restful method (Java EE) that returns back to the client a POJO serialized us bytes (using ByteArrayOutputStream, FlatBuffers or some other library)?

And the client to cast the bytes back to a POJO object by using jquery or javascript in general (us client side)?

What I had found until now, is receiving back a JSON/XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly converting POJO to bytes won't work as your client (javascript or so) won't know how to convert the bytes back to POJO. What you can do is this. Say your response is objA. The do this. Convert objA to String (JSON maybe) and then Base64 encode it to get byte[]. Put it inside a wrapper object objB. Return objB as a JSON from your service. Your client can just take that byte[] and since it knows that the byte[] is base64 it will be able to get the original information from there.
May I ask the intent of doing this instead of XML/JSON?

Comment: Ok, so in other words, there is no other way to make the deserialization on the client ( javascript ) side of a Jersey response. The purpose was to make a combination between Jersey (us functionality) and beans ( us the format of the response back ). To eliminate the need to make the conversion from JSON/ XML into POJO. Instead, receive directly the POJO. And also trying to use this advice: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwxIIUypnTE                                                                          (Of not sending JSON but to use bytes instead )

Comment: The POJO you're referring to is a Java object. If you use standard Java IO to serialize it, how will any client know how to de-serialize it back to data. There has to be some method to the serialization madness. You can send byte[] data directly to client too, without wrapping it in JSON object. Just ensure that you have a specific encoding for those bytes. Else client won't know what to do with those bytes.